# How to identify user using only phone in android

Tags: android

I am new in Android, so I have a question.
I want to create an app with such behaviors.
When user install the app he must type his e-mail and phone number, and some additional data. Next he creates an account (with button click).
Next when he enter the app second time he dont need to login, phone provides all identification needs (phone is an autentifiction card itself).
I forget to write if my database is Firestore, and I must identify phone in Firestore.

How to code such functionality?

Comment: Use a database; local or remote.

Comment: as mentioned by @javdromero you save all the required data in pref/DB and make an api call in the background to firebase apis or you own server APIs for authentication and session handling.

Answer (score -1):

Settings.Secure#ANDROID_ID returns the Android ID as unique for each user 64-bit hash string.

Android SDK Setting .Secure class would be provide Unique ID.

```
import android.provider.Settings.Secure;

private String android_id = Secure.getString(getContext().getContentResolver(),
                                                        Secure.ANDROID_ID);
```

**For helping material** : https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-ids

Comment: This has nothing to do with what was asked.

Comment: I am newbe in android, so please describe a scenario, how to use it. How to use it for register an user in Firestore, and how to identify user later.